# charm kub in openstack "... no metadata for "focal" images ... arch amd64"

Tags: juju, openstack, canonical, kubernetes

I am using ubuntu 18 to deploy charmed kubernetes to openstack. I have done the following which has worked but the instances are not being created.

I created controller like so

```
juju bootstrap openstack-cloud microstack --bootstrap-series=$OS_SERIES  --keep-broken \
  --metadata-source=~/simplestreams \
  --model-default network=test \
  --model-default external-network=external \
  --model-default use-floating-ip=true \
  --config use-default-secgroup=true \
--config apt-http-proxy=http://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config apt-ftp-proxy=ftp://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config apt-https-proxy=http://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config apt-no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0,127.0.1.1,127.0.1.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
--config juju-http-proxy=http://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config juju-ftp-proxy=ftp://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config juju-https-proxy=http://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config juju-no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0,127.0.1.1,127.0.1.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
--config snap-http-proxy=http://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config snap-https-proxy=http://proxy.domain.co.uk:3128 \
--config no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
--config logging-config="<root>=TRACE;unit=TRACE" \
 --debug
```

I added model `juju add-model k8s --debug`. To deploy I followed https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/openstack-integration with `juju deploy charmed-kubernetes --overlay openstack-overlay.yaml --trust --debug`

Status looks like in image

[image]

In openstack i have the following images

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to add the metadata to juju:

```
juju metadata add-image --arch amd64 --series focal <OpenStack image ID>
```